# Ubuntu compatibility with Lenovo ThinkPad e15 gen 4 with ryzen 5625U

Tags: drivers, laptop, compatibility

I am planning on buying a laptop for everyday use with Ubuntu. Since I live in India Lenovo does not ship with Ubuntu.

Please check the specs and let me know if I will have driver problems with installing the latest LTS version of Ubuntu.

```
System Specs:
Processor : AMD Ryzen™ 5 5625U Processor (2.30 GHz up to 4.30 GHz)
Operating System : DOS
Operating System Language : No Operating System Language
Total Memory : 24 GB (8 GB Soldered DDR4 3200MHz + 16 GB SO-DIMM DDR4 3200MHz)
First Solid State Drive : 256 GB SSD M.2 2242 PCIe Gen4 TLC Opal
Display : 39.62cms (15.6) FHD (1920 x 1080), IPS, Anti-Glare, Non-touch, 300 nits
Graphic Card : Integrated Graphics
Camera : FHD IR/RGB Hybrid with Microphone
Color : Black
Wireless : 11AX (2x2) & Bluetooth® 5.1
Ethernet : Wired Ethernet
Fingerprint Reader : Fingerprint Reader
Keyboard : Backlit, Black with Number Pad and Fingerprint Reader - India English
TPM Setting : Enabled Discrete TPM2.0
Absolute BIOS Selection : BIOS Absolute Enabled
Battery : 3 cell, 57Wh, Upto 12 hours
Power Cord : 65W USB-C 90%PCC Black (3pin) - India
Display Panel : 15.6" FHD (1920 x 1080), IPS, Anti-Glare, Non-touch, 300 nits, FHD IR/RGB Hybrid with Microphone, Black
Language Pack : Publication - Thai/Indonesian/English
Warranty : 1 Year Courier or Carry-in
```

Comment: @andrew.46 - I appreciate this has obviously had others vote to close as well, but I’m not convinced this is a hardware shopping question - OP is saying they intend to buy a particular computer and wants to check it’ll run Ubuntu. If they’d said ‘I need a laptop, what do you recommend for running Ubuntu’ then I’d agree … But personally I think this is reasonable for this site.

Comment: @Will I will reopen with some doubts, and let the Community decide... You may find that it will soon be closed as Duplicate, there are several Questions quite similar although some are quite old...

Comment: @andrew.46 - thank you: democracy in action - love it!

Comment: I am a Ubuntu user and like the specs of the given laptop. I am not sure how to test if the laptop will be compatible. On the previous assus laptop i had could not install Ubuntu and hence my apprehensions.

Comment: I disagree: we do not offer hardware recommedations, Clearly states so in the help.  https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8922/why-dont-we- allow-shopping-recommendations is still valid and on point.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I think it’ll run Ubuntu desktop fine. Nothing is certain until you try, but the specs certainly seem up to it. To date, I’ve never failed to install Ubuntu on a system that run Windows … and presumably that computer is made to run Windows. Some features might not work (eg fingerprint reader?), but overall I think you’ll have a system that works well for most things.

You may find the compatibility checker useful: https://ubuntu.com/certified/desktops

Comment: "Nothing is certain until you try, " answers need to be factual and that is also the reason we do not accept hardware recommedations: if it does not work someone needs to file a bug report and code a driver or alter a driver to make it work. Maybe it does not work  and maybe tomorrow it will.

Comment: @Rinzwind - my view is - this is someone with a genuinely reasonable question - they want to use Ubuntu (let’s encourage that!), have concerns it might not work because of past experience. We can say ‘no, off topic, can’t help’ or we can try to offer advice. You can never guarantee anything you advise will work on someone else’s system, but I think odds are that they will be able to install Ubuntu - I think better to try to give useful advice than offer no help. I deeply respect your posts on this site and hesitate to disagree with you, but I do think trying to help here is worthwhile.